# importing external ".txt" file in python

Tags: python, file, import

I am trying to import a text with a list about 10 words.

```
import words.txt
```

That doesn't work... 
Anyway, Can I import the file without this showing up?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/python/p1.py", line 9, in <module>
import words.txt
ImportError: No module named 'words'
```

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't actually do that. If you want to get those words you have to read them into your program. You can see how to do that with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922214/reading-a-text-file-and-splitting-it-into-single-words-in-python).

Comment: `import` is used to include library functions. To read files see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Did you try Googling "python import"?

Comment: What do you want to do with the list of words? Do you wish to create a list of the words, or just print them out exactly as they appear in the file? What does the file look like - are the words comma separated, on separate rows, etc.?

Answer (score 34):

You can import modules but not text files. If you want to print the content do the following:

Open a text file for reading:

```
f = open('words.txt', 'r')
```

Store content in a variable:

```
content = f.read()
```

Print content of this file:

```
print(content)
```

After you're done close a file:

```
f.close()
```

Comment: `'words.txt'` will open if it's in the same directory as the python file. If you need to grab a file from somewhere else just use it's path name like `'/Users/username/Desktop/sample.txt'`

Answer (score 7):

As you can't import a .txt file, I would suggest to read words this way.

```py
list_ = open("world.txt").read().split()
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer is modified from [infrared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378065/infrared)'s answer at [Splitting large text file by a delimiter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980288/splitting-large-text-file-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

```
with open('words.txt') as fp:
    contents = fp.read()
    for entry in contents:
        # do something with entry
```

Answer (score 3):

The "import" keyword is for attaching python definitions that are created external to the current python program. So in your case, where you just want to read a file with some text in it, use:

text = open("words.txt", "rb").read()

Answer (score 2):

numpy's genfromtxt or loadtxt is what I use:

```
import numpy as np
...
wordset = np.genfromtxt(fname='words.txt')
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765565/loading-a-dataset-in-python-numpy-when-there-are-variable-spaces-delimiting-co) got me headed in the right direction and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) gives you access to other modules in your program. You can't decide to import a text file. If you want to read from a file that's in the same directory, you can look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Here's another StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409780/reading-entire-file-in-python) about it.