# loading a dataset in python (numpy) when there are variable spaces delimiting columns

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, whitespace, delimiter

I have a big dataset contains numeric data and in some of its rows there are variable spaces delimiting columns, like:

```
4 5 6
7  8    9
2 3 4
```

When I use this line:

```
dataset=numpy.loadtxt("dataset.txt", delimiter=" ")
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2
```

How can I change the code to ignore multiple spaces as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default for `delimiter` is 'any whitespace'. If you leave `loadtxt` out, it copes with multiple spaces.

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> dataset = StringIO('''\
... 4 5 6
... 7 8     9
... 2 3 4''')
>>> import numpy
>>> dataset_as_numpy = numpy.loadtxt(dataset)
>>> dataset_as_numpy
array([[ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `numpy.genfromtxt` function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dataset = np.genfromtxt(dataset.txt) 
>>> print dataset
array([[   4.,    5.,    6.],
       [   7.,    8.,   19.],
       [   2.,    3.,    4.],
       [   1.,    3.,  204.]])
```

This is from the numpy documentation:

> By default, genfromtxt assumes delimiter=None, meaning that the line is split along white spaces (including tabs) and that consecutive white spaces are considered as a single white space.

Hope this helps!