# python - Read sections of a log file

Tags: python, file, file-handling, sections

My log file looks like this:

```
-------------
name=ABC
age=12
DOB=02/12/2001
EOL
-------------
name=DEF
age=9
DOB=06/20/2005
EOL
-------------
name=XYZ
age=23
DOB=02/12/1992
EOL
```

How can I read the file one section at a time? i.e. from the "---" to "EOL".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting large text file by a delimiter in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980288/splitting-large-text-file-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting large text file by a delimiter in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980288/splitting-large-text-file-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python example that's battle-tested with your input (pasted into "input.txt"):

```
 sections = []

 with open("input.txt") as file:
     section = ""
     for line in file.readlines():
         if line.strip() == "-------------":
             sections.append(section)
             section = ""
         else:
             section += line + "\n"
        print(sections)
```

Now you can iterate through the `sections` list and do whatever you want to each setion

Comment: Thanks! And how can I use regex matching to extract the names and other details from each section?

Comment: You can just go through each line in the `section` and `if section.startswith('name'): <process name>`.  Do this for each property.